# Linux: Rebuilding software Raid 1 fails when adding partition

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I had an issue yesterday with a software Raid, where one disk had to be replaced. I removed the partitions from the array using

```
mdadm /dev/mdx -r /dev/sdbx
```

After the failed drive has been replaced by the hosting center, I applied the partition table to the new disk (sdb was the bad device)

```
sgdisk -R /dev/sdb /dev/sda
```

Gave it a new id:

```
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb
```

Then I added all the partitions again using:

```
mdadm /dev/mdx -r /dev/sdbx
```

This went well for all partitions except one, which bails out after a few hours about at 60%
This is the current state of the raid:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md5 : active raid1 sda6[0] sdb6[2](S)
      2633910528 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md4 : active raid1 sda5[0] sdb5[2]
      16768896 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sda4[0] sdb4[2]
      2096064 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[2]
      268304192 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[2]
      523968 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[2]
      8384448 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

In syslog I can see messages like:

```
n 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.329021] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0xf00000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376449] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376475] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376477] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376479] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376481] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376483] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376486] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376487]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376495]         ce 1f 0d 58 
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376498] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376501] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376503] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376504] Read(16): 88 00 00 00 00 00 ce 1f 0b 80 00 00 04 00 00 00
Jan 23 14:24:04 rescue kernel: [11163.376513] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 3458141528
```

and

```
Jan 23 14:35:22 rescue kernel: [11840.396206] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jan 23 14:35:22 rescue kernel: [11840.396212] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jan 23 14:35:22 rescue kernel: [11840.396216] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jan 23 14:35:22 rescue kernel: [11840.396220] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jan 23 14:35:22 rescue kernel: [11840.396223] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jan 23 14:35:22 rescue kernel: [11840.396230] ata1: EH complete
Jan 23 14:35:52 rescue kernel: [11870.888343] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x40000007 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Jan 23 14:35:52 rescue kernel: [11870.945207] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:08:80:c3:58/04:00:ce:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 524288 in
Jan 23 14:35:52 rescue kernel: [11870.945207]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jan 23 14:35:52 rescue kernel: [11870.982487] ata1.00: cmd 60/80:10:00:c0:58/03:00:ce:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 458752 in
Jan 23 14:35:52 rescue kernel: [11870.982487]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.019291] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:f0:80:cb:58/04:00:ce:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq 524288 in
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.019291]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.055486] ata1: hard resetting link
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.707811] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.708270] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20131218/psargs-359)
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.708279] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff88041d869a88), AE_NOT_FOUND (20131
218/psparse-536)
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.709174] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20131218/psargs-359)
Jan 23 14:35:53 rescue kernel: [11871.709182] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff88041d869a88), AE_NOT_FOUND (20131
218/psparse-536)
```

I am able to mount /dev/md5 and list the files. However I can not add the new partition to the array.

Is there any way I can fix this without losing the data on the partition?

If not, is it possible to just format that single partition and then add the new drive again? I should have up to date backup of that partition, so that would not be an issue. If possible I just would like having to erase all partitions.

**smartctl output:**

/dev/sda:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.14.27] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
Serial Number:    Z1F1XJHC
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 04f3fc2c7
Firmware Version: CC24
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Fri Jan 23 16:16:32 2015 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Error SMART Values Read failed: scsi error aborted command
Smartctl: SMART Read Values failed.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 107 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 107 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13180 hours (549 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:49.931  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:48.680  READ DMA EXT
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      15:56:48.644  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      15:56:48.644  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      15:56:48.644  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 106 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13180 hours (549 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:45.363  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:44.071  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:42.789  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:42.755  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:42.722  READ DMA EXT

Error 105 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13180 hours (549 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:15.716  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:12.832  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:11.540  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:10.290  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:09.448  READ DMA EXT

Error 104 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13180 hours (549 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:56:02.563  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:55:59.655  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:55:58.319  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:55:58.069  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:55:57.838  READ DMA EXT

Error 103 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13180 hours (549 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 80 ff ff ff ef 00      15:55:51.995  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff ef 00      15:55:50.735  READ DMA EXT
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      15:55:50.700  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      15:55:50.700  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      15:55:50.699  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4561         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2977         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         5         -

Device does not support Selective Self Tests/Logging
```

/dev/sdb:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.14.27] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST33000650NS
Serial Number:    Z295TK0G
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 04f891ded
Firmware Version: 0004
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Fri Jan 23 16:15:30 2015 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 255) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x10bd) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   078   053   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       70825960
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       11
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   088   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       791126750
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       7155
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       11
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   043   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 34 (5 173 37 27)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   057   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 24 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   018   007   000    Old_age   Always       -       70825960
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 18 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 18 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5559 hours (231 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 18 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:52:28.560  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:52:28.560  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:52:28.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:52:28.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:52:28.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 17 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5559 hours (231 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:52:13.471  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 58 d0 57 44 43 00  26d+03:52:13.471  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 02 08 90 6d 49 00  26d+03:52:13.471  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  26d+03:52:13.470  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  60 00 00 e0 42 20 4e 00  26d+03:52:13.422  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 16 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5559 hours (231 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:56.176  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:56.176  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:56.175  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 e0 0d 20 4e 00  26d+03:51:56.116  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 e0 0c 20 4e 00  26d+03:51:56.114  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 15 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5559 hours (231 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 50 59 cb 43 00  26d+03:51:24.077  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:24.077  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 e0 c5 1c 4e 00  26d+03:51:24.076  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  26d+03:51:24.071  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  60 00 08 28 46 c1 43 00  26d+03:51:22.717  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 14 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5559 hours (231 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:02.317  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:02.317  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  26d+03:51:02.316  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:02.303  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  26d+03:51:02.300  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7071         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7060         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5600         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2489         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks to me very much down to this unrecovered read error on `sda`.  That's the only currently-live half of the mirror, so if it can't be read, there's no way to cleanly made `sdb6` a copy of `sda6` and resync the mirror.

I note it's been nearly 10,000 hours since `sda` last passed a selftest, so the idea that hardware failure might've crept up on it, too, seems unsurprising.  If you can still read the contents of `/dev/md5` you've dodged a bullet, it means the unreadable block isn't inside a file.  Backup the contents of that partition, then replace `sda` as well, **and this time replace it with a reasonably new disc**.  Once everything's stable, remake the `md5` device, and restore from the backup.

And once you get this system back up, make sure you have a `cron` job that runs `smartctl` tests on both drives at least every month or two, otherwise this is exactly the sort of warning you get that things are going Pear Shaped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, can I remove all the sda partitions from the raid (as I did with sdb), replace the disc, re-add the sda partitions (which should sync back from sdb) and then just make a new clean md5 device?

Comment: With the exception of `md5`, yes, it would appear so.  Don't forget to install GRUB on both HDDs if either partition includes the `/boot` partition; at the moment removing `sda` may render your system unbootable.

Comment: Thanks, I am working from a recovery system, so the issue that the system may not boot is not a problem. I am just wondering how I will fix the md5 partition after the new disk is built in and the other partitions are synced again.

Comment: Recreate the partition and restore from backups, as detailed in my answer above.

Comment: Probably I am just missing something. For md5 I have: one partition which is not completely readable (sda6) and one partition which did not sync fully (sdb6). If I remove the disk with the error (sda) and try to add the new disk to the raid, what will happen if mdadm tries to sync sda6 from the not fully completed sync from sdb6? I am afraid that will fail and I will not be able to assemble the raid again. Am I wrong here?

Comment: **Please read my answer carefully**; we are retreading the ground in that.  Yes, the resync will fail.  You have said that you are "*able to mount /dev/md5 and list the files*", so I'm suggesting that you backup the data from that partition, and destroy it.  Once you've replaced `sda` as well, you recreate that partition, and restore it from backups.

Comment: Ok, so I just will be able to recreate the partition sda6 on sda and sdb6 on sdb and I will be able to assemble those two partitions back together as md5? That would be all I need to know. I have snapshots of the data on that disk, so the data is not critical here. I just need to get the raid fully working again (hopefully without having to touch the other partitions). I am sorry if I am asking too many questions. This is the first time I am having to repair a raid.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: I was able to re-sync all partitions except md5 after the drive has been changed. Then I recreated the array for md5 and reformatted it. However I could not get the node to boot again. After I couldn't fix that with in a few hours, I finally just deleted everything and provisioned the node again.